# JAVA Apache HttpClient SSL TimedOut

Tags: java, apache, ssl, timeout, httpclient

I am currently working on a Java app and I am using Apache HttpClient 4.1.2. The problem is that when I'm trying to create a POST request with X-HTTP-Method-Override header set on "PUT" I get the following errors:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:789)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:746)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at requests.BlahBlahClass.run(BlahBlahClass.java:83)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I can't figure out what is the problem. Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client timed out waiting for the response. Either the timeout is too short or the server got stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have set timeout to 50s and now everything is ok.